# How to add an inside shadow to a white object on a colored background?

Tags: website-design, icon, paint.net, drop-shadow

Well, how to make image-2 from image-1 (in Paint.NET)?

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: inner glow, shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the white figures and delete them from the blue button.  Then, add your drop shadow to the remaining blue button.